# Как запретить разделение слов переносом в классе в CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня в CSS есть стиль, которым я покрываю нужное мне словосочетание (2 слова обычно). Хочу, чтобы эти два слова не разделялись переносом строки.

Например,

```
...бла бла бла <span class="class1">два слова</span> бла бла бла бла...
```

Допустим после слова "два" у меня должен идти перенос строки (потому что она заканчивается), но я хочу чтобы в таком случае перенос состоялся ДО слова "два", то есть перенеслось сразу словосочетание "два слова".

Глобально по документу прописан word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `white-space: nowrap` для элемента в котором не должен происходить перенос слов.

```css
.class1 { white-space: nowrap }
.class1:hover { white-space: normal }
div { word-wrap: break-word; width: 130px; border: solid }
```

```html
<div>.бла бла бла <span class="class1">два слова</span> бла бла бла бла...</div>
```

В этом сниппете для сравнения наведите указателем мыши на `два слова`.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с CSS: добавить `white-space: nowrap` для `span`, которым вы обворачиваете фразу.

Вариант с HTML: вместо `span` использовать тэг `nobr`.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого достаточно при написании пользоваться неразрывными пробелами , `&nbsp;` то есть это будет выглядеть примерно таким образом:

```
<span class="class1">два&nbsp;слова</span>
```

Другой вариант, если это пользовательские данные и вы используете PHP, тогда можно с передаваемой строкой провести такое колдовство:

```
$string = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$string);
```

Таким образом в передаваемой строке все пробелы будут заменены на неразрывные проблемы.

Comment: Как это нет? о_О